# I need pop-up image window once clicked on the image in partial view

Tags: image, asp.net-mvc-4, popup, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I am working on an admin layout. I have a partial view and there I have images. When I click on images, images is shown at the bottom of the page not shown as pop-up. But it is shown in a pop-up window when I get them into normal view. I am new on coding and don't have deep knowledge about CSS yet.

How can I see images in a pop-up window in partial view when I click on them as in normal view?

My partial view code:

```
    @model Urun



    <div class="onecolumn">
    <ul class="media_photos"  >
        @foreach (var item in Model.Fotolar.ToList())
        {
            <li style="margin-bottom:10px">
                <div style="height: 122px; margin-bottom:20px !important; width:         102px;text-align:center">
                    <a rel="slide" href="~/UrunFotolari/Buyuk/@item.FotoPath" title="@Model.Ad">
                        <img src="~/UrunFotolari/Kucuk/@item.FotoPath" alt="@Model.Ad" />
                    </a>
                    <a href="../FotoSil?id=@item.Id&urunId=@Model.Id">
                        <img style="border:none; height:20px;width:20px;" src="/Content/Admin/images/icon_delete.png" alt="delete" /></a>
                </div>
            </li>
        }
    </ul>

    <br class="clear" />
    @using (Html.BeginForm("FotoKaydet", "Admin", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        <input type="file" multiple="multiple" accept='image/*' name="fotolar" value="" />
        if (ViewBag.FotoHatasi != null && (bool)ViewBag.FotoHatasi)
        {
        <div class="alert_warning">
            <p>
                <img src="~/Content/Admin/images/icon_warning.png" alt="success" class="mid_align" />
                Bir fotoğraf seçin.
            </p>
        </div>
        }
        <input type="hidden"  name="urunId" value="@Model.Id" />
        <input type="submit" name="name" value="Kaydet" />
    }
</div>
```

and my controller:

```
    public ActionResult FotoIndex(int id = 0, bool hataVar = false)
    {
        Urun urun = db.Urunler.Find(id);
        if (urun == null)
            return View("_Hata");
        ViewBag.FotoHatasi = hataVar;

        return View(urun);
    }
```

Comment: write javascript code in View from where you are calling your Partial View.

Comment: there are a lot of different ways of doing a popup.  dialog is a popular one https://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Answer (score 0):

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.2.0/jquery.fancybox.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.2.0/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.2.0/jquery.fancybox.min.css">

<style type="text/css">


a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.primary-btn {
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(0deg, #235ee7 0%, #4ae7fa 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(0deg, #235ee7 0%, #4ae7fa 100%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(0deg, #235ee7 0%, #4ae7fa 100%);
}

.primary-btn {
    line-height: 36px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 30px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    border: none;
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: 500;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    position: relative;
}

.primary-btn {
    color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}

    .primary-btn:hover {
        background: transparent;
        color: #235ee7;
        border-color: #235ee7;
    }
</style>


 <a class="fancybox" href="~/Content/Admin/images/icon_warning.png" data-fancybox="gallery" title=""><img src="~/Content/Admin/images/icon_warning.png" alt="" /></a>
```